# SQL nesting subqueries with count

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

Is there a more convient and simpler way to write the following SQL-code?

```
SELECT
              products.name,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales` WHERE sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.payment_method = 'debt') AS debt, 
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales` WHERE sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.payment_method = 'cash') AS cash,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales` WHERE sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.payment_method = 'free') AS free

            FROM `sales`, `products`
            WHERE `sales`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
            GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional `SUM()` aggregation based on the `Payment_method`:

```
Select  P.name,
        Sum(Case When S.Payment_method = 'debt' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Debt,
        Sum(Case When S.Payment_method = 'cash' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Cash,
        Sum(Case When S.Payment_method = 'free' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Free
From    Sales       S
Join    Products    P   On  S.Product_id = P.Id
Group By P.Name
```

I've also added aliases to make it more readable, and changed the `GROUP BY` to be `P.Name` rather than `P.Id`.  `P.Id` does not appear in the `SELECT` statement, and while `MySQL` allows this, the results are left up to the compiler, which may give you something unexpected.

Comment: Can I add another JOIN statement?
    `JOIN S on S.time <= mytime`

Comment: That should be added as a `WHERE` clause, not a `JOIN` statement.

Comment: You might also want to add the condition: `where S.Payment_method in ('debt', 'cash', 'free'`). This will not change the result, but can increase the performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.name,
        SUM(IF(s.payment_method = 'debt',1,0)) debt,
        SUM(IF(s.payment_method = 'cash',1,0)) cash,
        SUM(IF(s.payment_method = 'free',1,0)) free
FROM products p
JOIN sales s
ON  s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

**Update** According to @jpw comment, I agree that could be simplified to:

```
SELECT  p.name,
        SUM(s.payment_method = 'debt') debt,
        SUM(s.payment_method = 'cash') cash,
        SUM(s.payment_method = 'free') free
FROM products p
JOIN sales s
ON  s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: You could reduce the conditional further to `SUM(s.payment_method = 'debt')` as MySQL evaluates boolean expressions as 1 or 0. :)